# Workflow that should only run on commits that only include markdown

Tags: github-actions

I have defined a workflow with the following:

```
name: Update Documentation
on: 
  push:
    paths-ignore: 
      - "!**.md"
  pull_request:
    paths-ignore: 
        - "!**.md"`
```

When I push a change of the YAML that contains this code it executes. This shouldn't have happened since the `"!**.md"` would have been true, right?

I tried setting the paths filter to `"**.md"` but then the workflow runs when I push a markdown file and any other type of file. That is why I switched to `paths-ignore` because I understand from the docs that if any of the paths match the `paths-ignore` then the workflow doesn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with this.

It doesn't appear to be in the docs [`on.<push|pull_request|pull_request_target>.<paths|paths-ignore>`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore) that the inverse case `!` works within `paths-ignore`; it's only suggested for use with `paths`, and in such a case it's required to have a positive match (without the `!`) as well, if you want the negative match (`!`) to work.

But even if it were valid, that wouldn't be what you're after. Saying "ignore all paths that aren't `**.md`" is not the same as saying "only run if all paths match `**.md`." If any path in the commit yields a positive match against the valid paths for triggering, it will trigger the workflow. There's no in-built mechanism for asserting that ALL paths match the triggering condition.

You have to roll your own, e.g. a workflow that triggers on any push that includes a `**.md` (the same as the condition you have in yours) and uses an initial job to check the files changed in this commit;

```yaml
name: "77951047"
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    paths:
    - '**.md'
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash
permissions: {}
jobs:
  check-md-only:
    name: This job was triggered
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      md-only: ${{ steps.test-md-only.outputs.md-only }}
    permissions:
        contents: read
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        fetch-depth: 2 # required to compare HEAD^
    - run: git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD
    - name: Test MD only
      id: test-md-only
      run: >-
        [ -z "$(git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD | grep -ve "\.md$")" ] &&
        echo "md-only=${{toJSON(true)}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT ||
        echo "md-only=${{toJSON(false)}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  build:
    name: Run if only MD files
    needs: ['check-md-only']
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ fromJSON(needs.check-md-only.outputs.md-only) == true }}
    steps:
    - run: echo ran
```